# MVC post CSV file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am looking for the better solution to import CSV file in ASP.NET MVC.

Basically want asynchronously submit the file to the controller and then i need to parse this comma delimited file, i dont need to store the file on server.

What is the batter way of submit this file to controller i may use?
Recently i found that solution http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/11/24/jquery-ajax-uploader-plugin-with-progress-bar/
but it is used flash to do the upload. i think i would prefer javascript to do that.

What do you think?

UPDATED
Some links to look at:

http://aspzone.com/tech/jquery-file-upload-in-asp-net-mvc-without-using-flash/

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload

http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i think i would prefer javascript to do that.

You cannot upload files using AJAX. If it is with the user consent you could create a simple html form with input type="file" field and then AJAXify this form using the [jquery.form](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) plugin. This plugin [supports also file uploads](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload). And to workaround the limitation that you cannot upload files using javascript it uses a hidden iframe.

Comment: @Joper, yes it usees iframes, not AJAX. Same as the plugin I suggested: jquery.form

Comment: i think ajax-upload is more advanced. What do you think?

Comment: @Joper, it depends on the functionality you are looking for. But, yes, it's definitely worth looking.

Comment: Trying to use jquery.form getting an error on line `form.submit();` `SCRIPT87: Invalid argument. 
jquery.form.js, line 347 character 5` any ideas? using this version https://raw.github.com/malsup/form/master/jquery.form.js

Comment: @Joper, no idea. Maybe you could start a new question and show the code you have tried.